# Read .csv - Separator Issues

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to read a csv from the following link: http://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/GDP.csv

I have two problems:

1. This table has different separators between its columns (e.g. the first and second column is separated by one comma, but the second and third column is separated by two commas).
2. Each row ends with 5 commas.

I thought about reading the table with the function read.fwf() to solve problems 1 and 2. However, I don't think this is a proper solution because values within some columns may vary in length (e.g. in the Country column one may find "United States" and "Italy").

Comment: Did you open this file with Excel? I did, and it's a mess. If I were you, I'd first clean it up by creating a clean sheet with the data I need and then trying to read it. You could also remove all commas first.

Comment: I just edited the link to download the csv directly. About opening the file in Excel, I guess it'd work, but I'm looking for a only-R based solution. Here isn't the case, but opening files in Excel may occur in losing leading zeros from cells, so I prefer learn to do everything from R. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: That makes sense, but I'd still recommend looking at the data first in Excel (Especially when it is so small) when downloading stuff from the net. You can never know what surprises are waiting for you which can mess up everything. How would @MrFlick know he needs to skip first 5 rows otherwise?

Comment: Totally agree, actually the reason why I thought there was 2 commas between the 2nd and 3rd column and not missing values was because I had opened it with the notepad from Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly this "CSV" file has been formatted to look pretty, not to actually be useful. It's not that it has different separators, it's that it has missing columns. How about cleaning it up with something like

```
dd <- read.csv("http://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/GDP.csv", skip=5, header=F)[,c(1,2,4,5)]
names(dd) <- c("CountryID","Ranking","Economy","GDP")
dd<-dd[dd[,1]!="",] #get rid of rows without IDs

head(dd)

#   CountryID Ranking        Economy          GDP
# 1       USA       1  United States  16,800,000 
# 2       CHN       2          China   9,240,270 
# 3       JPN       3          Japan   4,901,530 
# 4       DEU       4        Germany   3,634,823 
# 5       FRA       5         France   2,734,949 
# 6       GBR       6 United Kingdom   2,522,261
```

R doesn't like commas in numbers so you'll probably also want

```
dd$GDP <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",dd$GDP))
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yea, decided to get rid of all rows missing an ID value. Of course it's always a good idea to know thy enemy.

Comment: That's great, exactly what I was looking for. Could you please explain me the "[,c(1,2,4,5)]" at the end of the first line?

Comment: That's just to grab the subset of useful, non-empty columns. Only columns 1,2,4 and 5 seem to have data that you are interested in.